# Unable to remove a parameter in http request header using angular $http

Tags: angularjs, http

I need to perform a get and got this error from console

```
Request header field client_id is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

This is what I have for the header:

```
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, authorization, client_id
```

I would like to remove client_id from the request header for this one call and not affect the global settings.

Here is the code:

```
    $http.get(url,{
      headers: {"client_id": undefined }
    })
      .success(function (geoData) {
        d.resolve(geoData);
      })
      .error(function (err, status) {
        d.reject(err);
      });
```

But it has no effect. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

**This error raised by CORS problem**. [Read here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) for more infor about prelighted request. You need config your server to handle cos request to allow customer header parameter like 'client_id'. For example config value for **Access-Control-Allow-Headers** in **your server**:

```
'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' : 'client_id','Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length,
```

For handle header one by one base on request, you need define condition to build your header. it should be:

```
// build your header dynamic based on condition of request
var headerConfig = null;
if ('your condition to have client_id') {
    headerConfig = {"client_id": undefined }
}
else {
   headerConfig = {};
}

// request with headerConfig
$http.get(url,{
  headers: headerConfig
})
  .success(function (geoData) {
    d.resolve(geoData);
  })
  .error(function (err, status) {
    d.reject(err);
  });
```